# Verilog - masking using 1 bit input

Tags: verilog

I have a situation I'm not sure what's the right syntax that exists which can solve it.
In my code I have

```
reg [N-1:0] bit_list;
```

and another variable n which counts how many bits I inserted into bit_list.
Occasionally and according to the input - I need to, during a single posedge, shift bit_list by 1 then change bit_list[N-n] to my input. My idea was I can do the following

```
bit_list<=bit_list<<1 || X
```

Where X should be replaced some N-1 long vector that has zeros in all bits except for N-n. The problem is I don't know to describe such a vector - Hence my question.
I'm sure my problem is simple enough to be solved in a variety of simple ways, so any solution to my problem will work.

Sorry if my question is noobish as I'm still new, help will be appriciated of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask. (BTW `||` is logical-or, you want `|` a bitwise-or)

```
reg [N-1:0] mask;

mask = ({ {N{1'b0}},1'b0}) << n) - 1; // the concat is needed in case N > 32

bit_list<=((bit_list<<1) & ~mask) | (X & mask);
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed typos

Comment: Sorry for keeping comments: You mask is now always all ones. It is N*2 number of zeros, -1.

Comment: I was writing my own answer but abandoned as my solution was also a separate mask. I think mine was {N{1'b0,1'b1}} << (N-n-1); but I lost it.

Comment: I tried a variation of this code so it fits my intentions and something goes wrong. My code is: 
bit_list<=(bit_list<<1)|(in_bit&(mask<<N-n)); 

where mask is an N-1 reg and in_bit is a single bit input. 
(in_bit&(mask<<N-n)) results in a zero vector and doesn't have in_bit in my intended place. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: forgot to add: I defined mask with a starting value of 1. Also I need to emphasize it's & operator that causes it to become 0

Comment: You can simplify the mask if you hard code the bit size `(64'b1 << n)-1` will work for any mask size >=64 bits

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced the & with * and it worked. Thanks all!